# What is the url to get the top trending hashtags of twitter?

Tags: json, api, twitter

I want to display top 10 trending twitter hashtags country wise.

I have tried lot of api urls but those are not available right now. What is the current working url to get trending hashtags.

These are the links which i have tried already.

https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/23424975.json

https://developer.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/trends/available

http://search.twitter.com/trends/current.json

Comment: Version 1 of the Twitter API was retired about 7 years ago. You'd need to use version 1.1 today. You can find the documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place.html).

Comment: @Andy Piper Thank you